# WebAssembly dynamic module unloading

Tags: webassembly

I know it is possible to dynamically load modules in WebAssembly. Is it possible to dynamically unload modules?
I am considering an experimental porting into Wasm of a system that has a dynamic loader/linker with support for unloading. But can't find info on unloading of modules in Wasm.

Answer (score 4):

There is no need to unload Wasm modules, as they are garbage-collected automatically if no longer used. This is analogous to how JS code is handled.

Comment: Andreas, thanks for your answer, it helps me see how to clarify my question.

The system that I am considering has it's own compiler and dynamic linker/loader. If this is ported to Wasm, I would need the capability to 
A) Have initial "kernel" module loaded (this is done thru JS)

Comment: Whats your B) ? :)

Comment: Got distracted )
B) dynamically add modules to an already loaded set of modules (this is possible, as I understand, thru dlopen)
C) dynamically remove (unload) a module from the set of loaded modules. The other modules would stay loaded and continue working. Later on, a (possibly different) version of the unloaded module could be loaded again (i.e. a newer version of this module was compiled)
I guess what I'm describing is a development environment within WASM

Comment: Sure, but "unloading" only makes sense once you have dropped all references to the module and its exports. And at that point it is already done automatically by the engine.

Comment: Andreas, thanks for this invaluable info! Could you point me to where it is described in detail, like in the docs or smth? The whole idea of garbage collection of modules. Also, is there a way to 'kick' the GC - call it explicitly?

Comment: GC is not described in any spec, because its behaviour is, by design, not semantically observable. Also, on the Web, this is just part of the general JS/DOM GC. You cannot explicitly invoke GC, because that almost always is either a bad idea or meaningless -- the system knows much better when it is a good time to perform this work, and in modern collectors it is performed incrementally and in the background.